# How to query the backend of my Node.Js and updating the page without reloading the URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I want that when a user performs a certain action in the frontend of my Node.Js app, his data is sent to the script that processes the commands in the backend and then pings when the results are ready the frontend again and update the info that the user sees.

How to do that in a Node/Express app in the most efficient way? Shall I just use some kind of AJAX calls or there's a better way or a Node module or something that helps do it in a more Node-friendly way?

Thank you!

PS sorry if the question is a bit general, but it's only general because i do not know much about this particular aspect, so i seek to become a bit more specific in my point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is completely Node-friendly. Your case is a little tricky though, since you need to send information back from the server at an undetermined point in time.

Some common strategies to send a message from server to client are:

- Polling (client constantly sends request every X seconds to see if there's been an update)
- Long polling (variation of polling with typically less overhead)
- WebSockets (new 2-way communication protocol supported by modern browsers)

WebSockets are ideal, but aren't supported in older browsers. Luckily there's a library called [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) which will automatically check the client's browser and choose the best protocol based on what they can support. For this reason, `socket.io` is generally the go-to library for 2-way communication.

Whether or not you should use `socket.io` is up to you. If your backend script takes a long time to process (several minutes) and you have a lot of clients connecting, it may be worth doing regular polling with a large interval. This would reduce the load on the server since it doesn't need to maintain a constant connection with each client. If your script doesn't take too long and/or you don't have a huge number of clients connecting, `socket.io` will work great.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how long your `processes the commands in the backend` will take.

If your backend operation is not time consuming, eg: update a row in database. using ajax is a good idea.

If your backend need to send email, resize image or call third party api, which 
are time consuming. ajax will still work, but the user experience may be bad because they need to wait for a long time. (you can add some hint or animation to tell user be patient) Or you can make ajax calls every few seconds. (polling, which is already mentioned in the previous answer)

long polling and WebSocket are mainly for realtime things like web im (instant message) and if you really need realtime things, you can use services provided by `firebase` or `parse`. if you use socket.io, you may find some memory issues
and a lot to do if there is a boost in user number.

so i suggest using ajax.

BTW: some framework has built in realtime support.

- [metor](https://www.meteor.com/) a realtime web app framework in nodejs
- [sails](http://www.sailsjs.org/) a realtime mvc framework in nodejs